# Display column-based instead of Row-Based records in PHPMaker 10

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, customization

I'm having trouble and I wanna ask, if it's possible to have column-based tables when PHPMaker generates tables for records? Because when I generate it only generates row-based records. Copy-paste the link below to URL to understand. I'm sorry I'm not knowledgeable in PHP that much. It's just very easy to make a complete application with this program and the only thing stopping me is the format of how it's shown. An example of how I wanted it to look like would be [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0z9Vo.jpg)

I hope somebody answers! Thanking you all in advance!

Comment: What is the table structure you are using? Add table structure with sample data and expected output data and also the query which you had tried

Comment: Well, the structure only has 1 table, but a lot of fields (107 in total). Here's the table structure: http://i.imgur.com/XZg923S.png

And here's the sample of the table (I couldn't get to screenshot the whole page because my plugin wouldn't allow me to do so):

http://i.imgur.com/y3vZHRg.png

Comment: Your table is _far_ too wide regardless of what else you're trying - anything over ~20 columns is usually suspect.  It looks like you have at least a half-dozen additional tables trying to get out.

Comment: So, are there any other suggestions for it? Any tips would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of column based view is not suggested as it has many flaws when we try to display huge number of records. Adding pagination or sorting feature is very difficult and not user friendly.

As you have so many fields you could try to group them into tabs by relevancy. Once you put them under different tabs they can be easily navigated and easily fit into row based structure.

Creating tabs is PHPMaker is very easy, on field configurations screen you will get Page No config next to each field. By default it set to 1 you can set required page number as per your choice. Once you done go to Table config of the table which is second tab available for each table. Scroll down to bottom and and click on 3 dots next to Page Labels config (Under Multi Page Config). This will pop up a screen where you can add captions for your tab.